# Category with the 'categorgyurl' url_key attribute already exists

Tags: catalog, category

While programmatically creating category, using the below code, i got a error

```
Category with the 'categorgyurl' url_key attribute already exists
```

code:

```
        $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
        $category->setName('categorgyurl');
        $category->setUrlKey('categorgyurl');
        $category->setIsActive(1);
        $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
        $category->setIsAnchor(0);


        $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($root_catid);
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());              

        $category->save();
```

how to set, if `category url` already exits then make it change(ie. Rename it automatically/programmatically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setName('categorgyurl');
$category->setUrlKey('categorgyurl');
$category->setIsActive(1);
$category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
$category->setIsAnchor(0);

$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($root_catid);
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath()); 

$categoryWasCreated = false;
$currentUrlKey = $category->getUrlKey();
while (!$categoryWasCreated) {
    $categoryId = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getUrlKey(), 'url_key')->getId();
    if ($categoryId) {
        //if category with this url key exist add some unique part to the name
        //I used here time function but you can use something else
        $uniquePart = time();
        $category->setUrlKey($category->getUrlKey() . $uniquePart);
    } else {
        $category->save();
        $categoryWasCreated = true;
    }
}
```

Hope that is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need to generate URL key every time. Magento will automatically generate URL key from name. so you can remove `$category->setUrlKey('categorgyurl');` and then check result.

Comment: Sohil, Even automatic creation of url key if add same category name through this code, i got this error again. I need a solution if category urlkey already exits just rename its url key.